# What is the anonymous user in vsftp?

Tags: linux, ftp, user, vsftpd

I'm working on a new FTP server with Very Simple FTP (vsftp) and wondering how exactly the anonymous user works in vsftp. The [Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Very_Secure_FTP_Daemon) doesn't seem to give a good explanation of what it is, only that it can be used for login. Similarly, `man vsftpd.conf` doesn't explain it. Both seem to assume a working knowledge of this "anonymous user."

I got the FTP server working with the anonymous login (and had to guess username/password until I found out that the username is "anonymous" and password is arbitrary -- is this documented somewhere?), so my question is not about how to set it up (which the manuals explain well) but rather what the anonymous user *is*.

It doesn't seem to the `ftp` user (and not in the `ftp` group) which was my initial guess, because changing the permissions of the ftp directory to something like `550` doesn't allow the anonymous user to view it anymore. Similarly, options like `anon_other_write_enable` can change its permissions.

Is it a true Linux user? `vsftp` doesn't show up in `/etc/passwd`, so I would guess not. If not, what is it and how does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*All* file access goes through some "Linux user"; there is no such thing as an anonymous UID as far as process credentials go.

In vsftpd, the FTP users 'anonymous' and 'ftp' are mapped to the Unix account specified in the **`ftp_username`** config option, which is by default set to 'ftp' as well. (It's in the manual page under "String options".)

Note also the option **`anon_world_readable_only`**, which defaults to 'TRUE' – if enabled, vsftpd *only* allows the anonymous account to access files having o+r, regardless of any permission bits or ACLs allowing access to 'ftp' specifically.

The FTP username 'anonymous' itself is documented under the config option `anonymous_enable`.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for covering all the details. I didn't understand the `anon_world_readable_only` property when I read it in the manpage, and I guess I missed the description in `anonymous_enable`.